# Editor keydown lock for alphanumeric keys

Tags: javascript, events, editor

I'm working on an editor project, and realized in common used editors the UX for alphanumeric key input is registered on keyDown once, for other keys is simple on keyDown. eg. If you press `a` and hold, it'll insert `a`, but for `.` it'll insert `......`. So I had my implementation like this:

```
let keydownLock = false
const onKeyUp = () => { keydownLock = false }
const onKeyDown = () => {
  if (keydownLock) return
  if (isAlphanumeric) keydownLock = true
  other key handling...
}
```

My questions are:

1. If this is an editor standard UX for key input, please point me to some references.
2. Is there some special key event for easier implementation?

**Update**:
I realized it's standard behavior for all content-editable HTML element. So no need to implement anything. But my first question still remains.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. You say that alphnumeric is registered on `keyDown` once. What does that even mean? Then, you say that other keys are registered on `keyDown` as if it was contradictory to how alphanumeric keys are processes but you say `keyDown` for both.

Answer (score 0):

From what i could understand from your question, basically in Javascript the  onkeypress event is similar to the onkeydown event, but it does not fire for all key types in all browsers.

If you want to cancel input from the keyboard, it is better to cancel both the onkeydown and onkeypress events,because sometimes the onkeypress/onkeydown event needs to be canceled depending on the browser and the type of the pressed key. For example, if you want to cancel the cursor left, up, right and down keys, the onkeydown event needs to canceled in Internet Explorer, Firefox, Google Chrome and Safari and the onkeypress event needs to be canceled in Opera. For alphanumeric characters, canceling one of the onkeydown and onkeypress events is sufficient.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, it's a bit hard to describe, maybe it's easier just try press and hold `a` and `.` in an editor and observe the difference. I'm trying to find why is this behavior across all editors.

Comment: You can just use this comment textarea to try it. I also tried on Google doc, Word, sublime, vscode.